# Terminology "bounded away"

Tags: analysis, terminology

Let $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. We say that $f$ is **bounded away from $1$**, if there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that either $f(x) \geq 1 + \epsilon$ or $f(x) \leq 1 - \epsilon$ for all $x \in [a, b]$.

I am wondering whether there is a similar terminology for "bounded above by $1$ and away from $1$": there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f(x) \leq 1 - \epsilon$ for all $x \in [a, b]$. Do we say that $f$ is "bounded above by and away from $1$"?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would simply say "bounded above away from $1$".

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you so much. That sounds great!